# Mapping a "Command" key in neovim / alacritty

Tags: neovim, macos, alacritty

I am failing to map <kbd>Command+T</kbd>, <kbd>Command+[</kbd> and <kbd>Command+]</kbd> keys in Neovim under macOS / Alacritty.

I've reduced my Alacritty to be minimal:

```yaml
env:
  TERM: xterm-256color
font:
  size: 16
key_bindings:
  - {key: T,        mods: Command, chars: "\×80\xfc\x80t"}
  - {key: LBracket, mods: Command, chars: "\×80\xfc\×80["}
  - {key: Bracket,  mods: Command, chars: "\×80\xfc\×80]"}
```

And also Neovim's:

```lua
vim.kevmap.set('n', '<D-t>', vim.cmd.tabnew)
vim.keymap.set('n', '<D-[>', vim.cmd.tabprevious)
vim.keymap.set('n', '<D-]>', vim.cmd.tabnext)
```

1. I went to `nvim`,
2. entered the following command,

   ```
   echo "\<D-t>"
   ```
3. got an output:

   ```
   <80><fc><80>t
   ```
4. used the output to add a binding in Alacritty:

   ```
   - { key: T, mods: Command, chars: "\x80\xfc\x80t" }
   ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Please don’t post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/). Just post code blocks of your config files.

Comment: Does mapping `×80\xfc\x80t` work? You can try using `<C-v><C-t>` to insert that direct sequence, but you can probably also use some escape sequence (I'm not that familiar with Neovim's lua stuff).